# Angularjs q.all firing before promises conclude

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have the following (Adding promises to an array):

```
function processInformation() {
    var promisesArray = [];
    for(var i =0; i<a.length; i++) {
      var promise = this.getValue().then((response) => {
            this.processValue(response).then(()=> {
                  // it gets here
            });
       });
      promises.push(promise).
    }

 return $q.all(promises);
}
```

And then I make the call like so:

```
  getInformation().then((response) =>{
        // wait for the promises to be resolved
         this.processInformation().then((r) => {
           // never gets here
          });
    }).finally(()=> {
      //gets here
});
```

This is not working as expected because it does get to call the finally and it never goes inside the processInformation. I also tried using angular.forEach instead of the for loop (as advised in other posts) but it still doesn't work correctly. It does go inside the then of the processValue() though. What is another way to approach this?

Comment: Your post is contradictory. You say that it never goes inside `processInformation` and that it does go inside `processValue`, but the first function you posted _is_ `processInformation` and `processValue` is _inside_ that. Could you post an actual example that doesn't contradict itself? Also, we have no idea what `this`, `a`, or a variety of other things are. There is a lot of missing information here. Lastly, it looks like you're probably using the wrong `this` when (supposedly) calling `processInformation`. Are there any console errors you haven't told us about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise object which you are creating doesn't returning promise object, Also you should return response from inner promise to resolve it.

**Code**

```
function processInformation() {
    var promisesArray = [];
    for(var i =0; i<a.length; i++) {
      var promise = this.getValue().then((response) => {
            return this.processValue(response).then((data)=> {
                  // it gets here
                  return data;
            });
       });
      promises.push(promise).
    }

 return $q.all(promises);
}
```